# Bubbly/Wet Sounds with FM synthesis

Tags: design, sound, synthesis, frequency, modulation

Here's an example:

(wet/bubbly sounds all throughout, particularly in first 10 seconds)
I'm wondering if anybody knows any tricks on producing these kinds of sounds, and maybe FM is overkill. A simple sine wave with an adsr on pitch and volume that has a fast attack and short decay produces something of a bubbly noise but I'm looking for a richer sound.

I've had this sound in my head of a low sub bass that morphs into something like the sound of a bunch of bubbles and am hoping to get some insight as to how to realize it.

I've done some research on making "squelchy" basses with fm. One trick is having all the operators out of phase. The sounds that I've made by following "squelchy bass" tutorials all sound too distorted. I'm looking for a nice, natural, round, wet sound... if that means anything to anyone. Anyone know any tricks? Relevant tutorials, ideas, thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If your original attempt sounds good, but dry, try adding some effects. A very small, short reverb, a close chorus and maybe a flanger.
Try some other effects to liven it up and give it a more natural feel.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't listen to the example in the question, because the video is no longer available.

I have recorded a short video about this stuff after I was making sound effects for a commercial involving a lot dense of liquids splashing. It proven to be very effectve:

Also I have much more recent a video about create sound effect of a water stream:

It's not using plain FM, rather resonant bandpass filters with a randomized LFO to create the main "bubbly" feature of the sound.

I hope it's still going to be helpful though.